# Running Python script from PHP but its not working

Tags: python, php, exec, python-pdfkit

HI I am using PHP to execute python script:

**pdf.py**

import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('https://www.google.co.in/','google.pdf');

**data.php**

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

exec("python pdf.py");

I tried executing ython file using php with above data, But script not run .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `exec("python pdf.py", $response, $error_code);` and see if anything useful is returned in `$response` or `$error_code`?